# Making IE9 CSS nth-child rule work on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

In IE9 this code works:

```
body.country-XYZ .abc:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
 }
```

Since `:nth-child()` works starting from `IE9`, how could I make it work on `IE8` ?
Please provide alternative for nth-child(2n+1) that works for ie8

Comment: can you add HTML markup as well or fiddle

Comment: I'm affraid you will have to implement this using javascript, or customize your server-side code to incject proper classe(s) to 3rd child.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan why was that other question closed as "unclear"? I think it's pretty clear what the original poster is looking to do.

Comment: @Cupcake I don't know why [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711879/alternative-rule-to-nth-child-for-ie8) was marked unclear. I also tried to edit his question to improve it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript in order to emulate the :nth-child() pseudo-class in IE8. Check out `http://selectivizr.com/`

Comment: hmm! never heard of this library, but looks promising.  +1

Comment: you got a downvote from somebody because of your wording.  If you say something like "You need to use JavaScript in order to emulate the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class in IE8.  Check out `http://selectivizr.com/`"  Reword your answer accordingly. i think you'll lose the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

not really elegant CSS code, but you can hide the  `.abc` elements starting from the 3<sup>rd</sup> with

```
body.country-XYZ .abc + .abc + .abc {
    display:none;
}
```

and then you can show them again from the 4<sup>th</sup> element

```
body.country-XYZ .abc + .abc + .abc + .abc {
    display: block; /* or whatever is the default display value of .abc */
}
```